# The View Controller in my storyboard not match with the ViewController.xib

Tags: storyboard, xib, xcode4.5, viewcontroller

I'm very new to Xcode so this is probably very newby but i don't figure it out yet.

Question:
I've made in my storyboard a few View Controllers with some buttons etc. They are linked to each other and it's worked fine. Now i have some code for closing the keyboard. So i've add ViewController h/m/xib files with same names as the ViewControllers in my storyboard. But the xib files doesn't include the same buttons etc as the ViewController in my storyboard.

Do i something very stupid, and will it won't work this way or?

Thank you a lot if you help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a storyboard, you shouldn't need xib files.  There are different methods for dealing with each and it's best not to mix them up.  The .h/.m files you created should be fine.

If your storyboard's view controller classes match the classes you've created in code, then you can connect outlets and actions from the buttons to the code files.